# unable to download file from finance yahoo from internet to the sdcard

Tags: android, web-services, yahoo-finance

```
    public void downloadFileViaHTTP()
    {
        Log.d("downloadFileViaHttp", "downloadFileViaHTTP...");
        try 
            {
                  String urlFile = "http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=ACC.NS+AMBUJACEM.NS+ASIANPAIN.NS+AXISBANK.NS+BAJAJ-AUT.NS+BANKBAROD.NS+" +               "BHARTIART.NS+BHEL.NS+BPCL.NS+CAIRN.NS+CIPLA.NS+COALINDIA.NS+DLF.NS+DRREDDY.NS+GAIL.NS+GRASIM.NS+HCLTECH.NS+HDFC.NS+HDFCBANK.NS+ HEROHONDA.NS+HINDALCO.NS+HINDUNILV.NS + +"HEROHONDA.NS+HINDALCO.NS+HINDUNILV.NS+ICICIBANK.NS+IDFC.NS+ITC.NS+INFY.NS+JINDALSTE.NS+JPASSOCIA.NS+KOTAKBANK.NS+LT.NS+LUPIN.NS+M%26M.NS+"+ "MARUTI.NS+NTPC.NS + ONGC.NS+PNB.NS+POWERGRID.NS+RANBAXY.NS+RELIANCE.NS+RELINFRA.NS+SBIN.NS+SESAGOA.NS+SIEMENS.NS+SPARC.NS+TATAMOTOR.NS+"+"TATAPOWER.NS+TATASTEEL.NS+TCS.NS+ULTRACEMC.NS+WIPRO.NS+ %5ENSEI&f=snl1hgp";

            URL url = new URL(urlFile);
            Log.d("url", url.toString());
            BufferedReader reader=null;
            Log.d("1","1");
            // create the new connection
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            Log.d("downloadFileViaHttp:HttpURLconnection", " " + urlConnection);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            //and connect!
            Log.d("2","2");
            urlConnection.connect();

            // pointer to the downloaded file path
            File sdcard= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); 
            File MyFilePtrDest=new File(sdcard,"quotes.csv");

            Log.d("downloadFileViaHttp","localFileName = " + MyFilePtrDest.toString());

            // this will be used in reading the data from the Internet
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            // this will be used to write the downloaded data into the file we
            // created
            FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(MyFilePtrDest);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bufferLength = 0; // used to store a temporary size of the buffer               
            // write buffer contents to file
            while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer))>0) 
            {
            Log.d("content","content "+inputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferLength));
            // add the data in the buffer to the file in the file output
            // stream (the file on the sd card
            fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            }
                inputStream.close();
                // close the output stream when done
                // fileOutput.flush();
                // fileOutput.close();
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                // data were not found
                dataNotFound = true;``
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

I'm trying to download the csv file from the yahoo finance whenever the pointer reaches to the statement `urlconnection.connect()` in the above code and  it gives me the `java.net.unknownHostException`. How can I solve the problem in the code above?

below is the log cat

> 03-29 19:10:09.770: W/System.err(32292):
>   java.net.UnknownHostException: finance.yahoo.com 03-29 19:10:09.770:
>   W/System.err(32292):  at
>   java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:506) 03-29
>   19:10:09.770: W/System.err(32292):    at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:294) 03-29
>   19:10:09.770: W/System.err(32292):    at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:256) 03-29
>   19:10:09.770: W/System.err(32292):    at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:69)
>   03-29 19:10:09.770: W/System.err(32292):  at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:48)
>   03-29 19:10:09.770: W/System.err(32292):  at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:322)
>   03-29 19:10:09.770: W/System.err(32292):  at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:89)
>   03-29 19:10:09.770: W/System.err(32292):  at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHttpConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:285)
>   03-29 19:10:09.770: W/System.err(32292):  at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.makeConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:267)
>   03-29 19:10:09.770: W/System.err(32292):  at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:205)
>   03-29 19:10:09.770: W/System.err(32292):  at
>   com.indusa.stockapp.stockListing.StockListing.downloadFileViaHTTP(StockListing.java:252)
>   03-29 19:10:09.770: W/System.err(32292):  at
>   com.indusa.stockapp.stockListing.StockListing.onCreate(StockListing.java:99)
>   03-29 19:10:09.770: W/System.err(32292):  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
>   03-29 19:10:09.770: W/System.err(32292):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1623)
>   03-29 19:10:09.770: W/System.err(32292):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
>   03-29 19:10:09.770: W/System.err(32292):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121) 03-29
>   19:10:09.770: W/System.err(32292):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
>   03-29 19:10:09.770: W/System.err(32292):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 03-29
>   19:10:09.780: W/System.err(32292):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130) 03-29 19:10:09.780:
>   W/System.err(32292):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3770) 03-29
>   19:10:09.780: W/System.err(32292):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 03-29
>   19:10:09.780: W/System.err(32292):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 03-29 19:10:09.780:
>   W/System.err(32292):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
>   03-29 19:10:09.780: W/System.err(32292):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:670) 03-29
>   19:10:09.780: W/System.err(32292):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: it looks fine, you probably have to restart your emulator or your internet connection is not available on your computer.

Comment: both are working properly i have checked almost 100 times but i running diretly on device

Comment: try with a shorter query portion of the url. try encoding the url due to all the special chars , spaces in the query portion of url.

Comment: http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=ACC.NS+AMBUJACEM.NS+ASIANPAIN.NS+AXISBANK.NS+BAJAJ-AUT.NS+BANKBAROD.NS  try removing '+' from the link @ end of it

Comment: i have tried both by removing the + sign and by using shorter query but both wont work...!